# How do I get the following combined table through SAS?

Tags: sas

My goal is to combine these tables into one without having to manually run my macro each time for each column.

The code I currently have with me is the following:

```
%macro task_Oct(set,col_name);

data _type_;
set &set;
call symputx('col_type', vtype(&col_name));
run;

proc sql; 
create table work.oct27 as
select "&col_name" as variable, 
"&col_type" as type, 
            nmiss(&col_name) as missing_val, 
            count(distinct &col_name) as distinct_val
    from &set;
quit;

%mend task_Oct;

%task_Oct(sashelp.cars,Origin)
```

The above code gives me the following output:

```
|Var   |Type     |missing_val|distinct_val|
|Origin|Character|0          | 3          |
```

But the sashelp.cars data sheet has 15 columns and so I would like to output a new data sheet which has 15 rows with 4 columns.

I would like to get the following combined table as the output of my code:

```
|Var   |Type     |missing_val|distinct_val|
|Make  |Character|0          | 38         |
|Model |Character|0          | 425        |
|Type  |Character|0          | 6          |
|Origin|Character|0          | 3          |
...
...
...
```

Since I'm using a macro, I could run my code 15 different times by manually entering the names of the columns and then merging the tables into 1; and it wouldn't be a problem. But what if I have a table with 100s of columns? I could use some loop statement but I'm not sure how to go about that in this case. Help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Is the goal to have a macro where you only have to pass in the name of the dataset and it will generate the output with summary of all of the variables in the dataset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main output you appear to want can be generated directly by PROC FREQ with the NLEVELS option.  If you want to add in the variable type then just merge it with the output of PROC CONTENTS.

```
ods exclude all;
ods output nlevels=nlevels;
proc freq data=sashelp.cars nlevels;
  tables _all_ / noprint ;
run;
ods select all;
proc contents data=sashelp.cars noprint out=contents;
run;

proc sql;
create table want(drop=table:) as 
  select c.varnum,c.name,c.type,n.*
  from contents c inner join nlevels n
  on c.name=n.TableVar
  order by varnum
;
quit;
```

Result

```
                                                                    NNon
                                                       NMiss        Miss
Obs    VARNUM    NAME           TYPE     NLevels      Levels      Levels

  1       1      Make             2           38           0          38
  2       2      Model            2          425           0         425
  3       3      Type             2            6           0           6
  4       4      Origin           2            3           0           3
  5       5      DriveTrain       2            3           0           3
  6       6      MSRP             1          410           0         410
  7       7      Invoice          1          425           0         425
  8       8      EngineSize       1           43           0          43
  9       9      Cylinders        1            8           1           7
 10      10      Horsepower       1          110           0         110
 11      11      MPG_City         1           28           0          28
 12      12      MPG_Highway      1           33           0          33
 13      13      Weight           1          348           0         348
 14      14      Wheelbase        1           40           0          40
 15      15      Length           1           67           0          67
```

The NMissLevels variable counts the number of distinct types of missing values.

If instead you want to count the number of observations with (any) missing value you will need to use code generation.  So use the CONTENTS data to generate an SQL query to generate all of the counts you want into a single observation with only one pass through the data. You can then transpose that to make it usable for re-merging with the CONTENTS data.

```
filename code temp;
data _null_;
  set contents end=eof;
  length nliteral $65 dsname $80;
  nliteral=nliteral(name);
  dsname = catx('.',libname,nliteral(memname));
  file code;
  if _n_=1 then put 'create table counts as select ' / ' ' @ ;
  else put ',' @;
  put 'nmiss(' nliteral ') as missing_' varnum 
    /',count(distinct ' nliteral ') as distinct_' varnum
  ;
  if eof then put 'from ' dsname ';';
run;
proc sql;
%include code /source2;
quit;
proc transpose data=counts out=count2 name=name ;
run;

proc sql ;
create table want as 
  select c.varnum, c.name, c.type 
       , m.col1 as nmissing
       , d.col1 as ndistinct
  from contents c 
  left join count2 m on m.name like 'missing%' and c.varnum=input(scan(m.name,-1,'_'),32.)
  left join count2 d on d.name like 'distinct%' and c.varnum=input(scan(d.name,-1,'_'),32.)
  order by varnum
;
quit;
```

Result

```
Obs    VARNUM    NAME           TYPE    nmissing    ndistinct

  1       1      Make             2         0           38
  2       2      Model            2         0          425
  3       3      Type             2         0            6
  4       4      Origin           2         0            3
  5       5      DriveTrain       2         0            3
  6       6      MSRP             1         0          410
  7       7      Invoice          1         0          425
  8       8      EngineSize       1         0           43
  9       9      Cylinders        1         2            7
 10      10      Horsepower       1         0          110
 11      11      MPG_City         1         0           28
 12      12      MPG_Highway      1         0           33
 13      13      Weight           1         0          348
 14      14      Wheelbase        1         0           40
 15      15      Length           1         0           67
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your effort. The column "Cylinders", however, has 2 missing values and I'd like my output table to display that information clearly. There are 2 '.' in the Cylinders column in the sashelp.cars data sheet and I don't want it to be considered as 1 just because they are both '.'. When I run the code, I'd like my output data table to make it clear that there are indeed 2 missing values.

Comment: Your original code was not counting how many observations had missing values.  If you only give the NMISS() function one variable to test the result can only ever be 0 or 1.

Comment: My original code does display 2 missing values for "Cylinders". Try it. Just replace Origin with Cylinders in the macro.

Comment: So SAS seems to have added NMISS() as one of their non-standard SQL aggregate functions that is distinct from the normal NMISS() SAS function.  Note also that the aggregate function NMISS() seems to work on both numeric an character values. The normal SAS function NMISS() only works a numeric values , unlike the MISSING() or CMISS() SAS functions that work on either numeric or character values.

Comment: Note if you want to use only ANSI standard SQL code you need to use `count(*)- count(cylinders)` to calculate the number of observations with missing value for CYLINDERS variable.

Comment: Could you also please explain what the following part of your code does? if _n_=1 then put 'create table counts as select ' / ' ' @ ;
  else put ',' @;

Comment: \_N_ is the automatic iteration counter.  So that IF/THEN/ELSE block writes the first line of the generated SQL query on the first pass (first variable name)  and then for the rest of the variables it writes just the comma you need to separate the column list in the generated SQL code.  The trailing @ allows the next PUT statement to continue writing on the same line.