# Could someone please explain what the following lines of this code do?

Tags: sas

This is the code that I have with me:

```
%let data=sashelp.cars;

    proc transpose data=&data(obs=0) out=names;
       var _all_;
       run;
    proc sql;
       select cats('_',_name_,'=missing(',_name_,');') into: stmts separated by ' ' from names;
       run;
    
    data missing;
       set &data;
       _BIGN = 1;
       /*%m_expand_varlist(data=&data,expr=cats('_',_name_,'=missing(',_name_,');'));*/
       &stmts;
       keep _:;
       run;
    proc summary data=missing;
       var _numeric_;
       output out=smry sum=;
       run;
    proc transpose data=smry(drop=_type_ _freq_) out=smry_;
       run;
```

The goal of this code is to output the number of missing values for both character and numeric variables in the data set. The code accomplishes that objective but I have difficulty in understanding the purpose of certain lines in the code.

May I know what the following part of the code does?

```
 select cats('_',_name_,'=missing(',_name_,');') into: stmts separated by '  ' from names;
```

I understand that the into part just stores the value into the macro variable stmts but what does "separated by ' ' from names" in the above line mean?

```
data missing;
       set &data;
       _BIGN = 1;
       &stmts;
       keep _:;
       run;
```

And in the above portion of the code, what is the purpose of "keep *:"? What does the "*:" do in that? And is the "_BIGN = 1" necessary?

And also in the final output table called smry_, I get underscores before the names of the variables. But I don't need these underscores. What can I do to remove them? When I removed the underscore after the "keep *:", the underscores in the smry* table went away but I was left with only 10 rows instead of 15. Help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Use the variable number instead to name your calculated variables to avoid any possibility of name conflicts.  See the answer to this question which seems to want the exact same result as you do.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74221509/how-do-i-get-the-following-combined-table-through-sas/74222731#74222731

Comment: This question seems to be asking what the code in this answer does: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74362667/3560695

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before answering your questions, let me disclaim that this is not the way to go if you simply want a count of missing values for each numeric variable in your data.

However, this seems to be more of a practice assignment than an actual problem.

1. The Separated By Clause simply inserts the specific string between the values in the macro variable if the data source has >1 items. In this case the names data set has 15 items, so all 15 values are listed with a few spaces between them.
2. The colon operator in the keep statement tells the data step to keep only variables prefixed with an underscore.
3. _BIGN is not strictly necessary. However, it seems that the author of the code wants a simple count of observations in the final data set. That is all it does.
4. The underscores are applied to each variable name in the creation of the macro variable in. It is probably done to avoid conflicts between variable names (though this is technically still possible). Obviously, you can simply remove the underscore in the final data set.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In the following line of the code, is the word "missing" here a function? "select cats('_',_name_,'=missing(',_name_,');') into: stmts separated by ' ' from names;" though I understand the syntax of the code, I'm trying to understand the purpose of this line. What exactly seems to be the idea behind this particular line of code?

Comment: If the word "missing" here serves as a function, then I think understand the idea. So basically we get 1 for missing value and 0 otherwise. Then we use proc summary. And since proc summary only deals with numeric, that's why we had to use the missing function to get the values into 0 and 1s. This way, certain variables being character, didn't pose a problem?

Comment: @saslearner the STMTS macro variable will resolve to a list of `_var = missing(var);` statements, which is basically setting a flag to 0/1 if the value is missing. So yes, `missing(...)` is a function in this case.

Comment: Yes. Missing is a function here. The idea (I assume) is to create lines like _Make=missing(Make); and so on for as many variables as present in your data. All the generated statements are executed in the subsequent data step with the macro variable &stmts .

Comment: @saslearner, you beat me to it. Your assumption is correct.

Answer (score 1):

As you know the "into" clause stores the values in the macro variable. The "separated by" leads to a list of values stored in the variable with spaces as delimiter here. If you don't use this you have only the value of the first row in your macro variable.

The ":" is a wildcard that means you keep all the variables starting with an underscore:

```
keep _:;
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to remove the underscores in the final data set using the following code:

```
data _smry_(drop =  _name_);
set smry_;
name=compress(_name_, , 'kas');
run;
```

Comment: I hope you know what you are doing here? The function compress accepts as second parameter a list of characters that you want to remove and as the third parameter a list of modifiers. Here, you use the third parameter with the modifier 'kas' where 'a' stands for all alphabetic characters and 's' for space and 'k' for keeping these characters. Therefore, you remove any character that is not alphabetic or space. So, e.g.,  if your  column name is \_dest3lc this will result in destlc. If you use compress(_name_,'_') instead you get dest3lc.

Answer (score 0):

You could just rename the underscore variables back to original.

```
%let data=sashelp.heart;
proc transpose data=&data(obs=0) out=names;
   var _all_;
   run;
proc sql;
   select cats('Label _',_name_,'=',quote(_label_),';') into: lb_stmts separated by ' ' from names;
   select cats('_',_name_,'=missing(',_name_,');') into: stmts separated by ' ' from names;
   select cats('_',_name_,'=',_name_) into: rn_stmts separated by ' ' from names;
   run;

options symbolgen=1;
data missingV / view=missingV;
   set &data;
   &stmts;
   &lb_stmts;
   rename &rn_stmts;
   keep _:;
   run;
options symbolgen=0;
ods output summary=summary;
proc means data=missingV Sum Mean N STACKODSOUTPUT;
   var _numeric_;
   run;
ods output close;
proc print width=minimum label;
   label sum='#Missing' mean='%Missing';
   format sum 8. mean percentn8.1;
   run;
```

[image]